# Prove the series converges, which sequence is defined inductively

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Define $t_n$ inductively by $t_1=1$ and $\displaystyle t_{n+1}= \frac {t_{n}}{1+t_{n}^ \beta}$, where $\beta$ is fixed, $0 \le \beta \lt1$. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^ \infty t_n$ converges.
[Hint : Find a constant $C$ such that $t_n \le Cn^{-1/\beta}$.]

---

I am not sure this is right, so if you give me advice, that will be very appreciated.

since $\displaystyle t_{n+1}= \frac {t_{n}}{1+t_{n}^ \beta}$

$t_{n+1}({1+t_{n}^ \beta})= t_{n}$

So, $\sum_{k=1}^ \infty t_n$ =  $\sum_{k=1}^ \infty t_{n+1}({1+t_{n}^ \beta}) $

Let $g(n)=t_{n+1}, f(n)= ({1+t_{n}^ \beta})$

By Abel's test, if $g(n)$ is decreasing sequence and uniformly bounded, and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges uniformly, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(n)g(n)$ converges uniformly.

So, since $\displaystyle g(n)=t_{n+1} = \frac {t_{n}}{1+t_{n}^ \beta} $ and $t_n$  is non-negative,

$g(n)$ is a decreasing sequence and is bounded by $t_1=1$.

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges by Ratio test,
$\lim_{n\to \infty}|(1+t_{n+1}^{\beta})/(1+t_n^{\beta})| < 1$, since $t_n$ is a decreasing sequence.

So by Abel's test,
$\sum_{k=1}^ \infty t_n$ =  $\sum_{k=1}^ \infty t_{n+1}({1+t_{n}^ \beta}) = \sum_{k=1}^ \infty f(x)g(x)$ converges.

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed typo. I think fraction is too small to read but don't know how to make it bigger. Sorry for incovenience.

Comment: Did you try to follow the hint? Where did it lead you to?

Comment: It's shame that I even don't have any clue eventhough I got hint... I don't know how to start...

Comment: Actually, judging from your 4 questions so far, you reached a quite wrong idea of the nature of the site. Please read some howtoask advice and compare with your practice.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try more on it. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I tried hard for myself... can you give me some advice?

Comment: @qyong, I think Abel's test is a good idea... I like the setup.  The problem is that $\sum f(n)=\sum (1+t_{n}^{\beta})$ will not converge because $\lim (1+t_{n}^{\beta})=1\neq 0$.

Comment: @Did, qyong showed his attempt and got stuck.  I pointed out already why it cannot work.  I've made a CW post with a partial solution.  If you know how to prove the hint, I'd be curious to see how (I expected the induction to be easy but got stuck).

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry to ask but, before lecturing me, did you read the question as it was when I posted the two comments above?

Comment: @TravisJ Re the hint, the first thing to realize is that the function $u:x\mapsto x/(1+x^\beta)$ is increasing on $x\geqslant0$ (because $\beta<1$) hence $t_n\leqslant C/n^{1/\beta}$ implies $t_{n+1}\leqslant u(C/n^{1/\beta})$ and the job is to check that for some suitable $C\geqslant1$ (this restriction ensuring the base case $n=1$), $u(C/n^{1/\beta})\leqslant C/(n+1)^{1/\beta})$. If I am not mistaken, this holds for every $C$ such that  $(1+C^\beta)^\beta\geqslant2$, for example, for $C=2^{1/\beta^2}$.

Comment: The OP's solution fails at the step asserting that "$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}|(1+t_{n+1}^{\beta})/(1+t_n^{\beta})| < 1$, since $t_n$ is a decreasing sequence", since (1) the fact that $(t_n)$ is decreasing does not imply this limit holds, and (2) actually, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}|(1+t_{n+1}^{\beta})/(1+t_n^{\beta})| =1$ since $t_n\to0$.

Comment: @Did, Sorry if you felt like I was lecturing you.  I did read the original question (in fact before you commented I asked the OP to show his work and perhaps try to prove the hint via induction).  I deleted my comments once he edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove the hint, it is easy to finish (without using Abel's test).

For example, if you know that $t_{n}\leq Cn^{-1/\beta}$ and $0<\beta<1$ this is the same as saying $t_{n}\leq \frac{C}{n^{\alpha}}$ where $\alpha=\frac{1}{\beta}>1$.  Then, you can use direct comparison to say that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_{n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{C}{n^{\alpha}}$$

which latter sum converges since it is a $p$-series with $p>1$.

Trying to show the hint I've gotten stuck (which is why I made this post a community wiki, so that anyone else who sees how to finish can easily edit this and put the finishing touches on).  Here's what I have:

**Base Case**

$t_{1}=1 \leq \frac{C}{1^{\alpha}}$ for any $C\geq 1$.

**Inductive Step**

Suppose $t_{i}\leq \frac{C}{i^{\alpha}}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ (for some $C\geq 1$, yet to be determined).

Then
\begin{align*}
t_{n+1} &= \frac{t_{n}}{1+t_{n}^{\beta}} \\
        &\leq \frac{\frac{C}{n^{\alpha}}}{1+t_{n}^{1/\alpha}} \\
        &= \frac{C}{n^{\alpha}(1+t_{n}^{1/\alpha}) } \\
        &\vdots \:\:\:\:(???) \\
        &\leq \frac{C}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}
\end{align*}
The final result will hold if you can show that $(n+1)^{\alpha}\leq n^{\alpha}(1+t_{n}^{1/\alpha})$.  If it helps, $n^{\alpha}(1+t_{n})\leq n^{\alpha}(1+t_{n}^{1/\alpha})$, so you are also done if you can show that $(n+1)^{\alpha}\leq n^{\alpha}(1+t_{n})$.